# Using perl to write to a file in another directory (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: perl

I am trying to write some output to a file.
I want to create a new file in another directory than where the Perl script is located and write to it.
I have tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; 
use 5.16.0; 

my $filename = '/home/python/test.txt';

open (MYFILE, '>','$filename') || die;
print("File $filename opened successfully!\n");
printf MYFILE "test";
close(MYFILE);
```

However, this just creates a new file, named literally '$filename' in the same directory as where the Perl script is saved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are new to Perl and you care about learning it properly, feel free to post your working code on [codereview.se] in the Perl tag. We'll pick it up and give you constructive criticism. There are quite a few things you can improve.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks! I will definitely check that out in the future. I will be working with Perl quite a lot, so constructive feedback will be really appreciated!

Comment: May I suggest you start with a good book? If you are familiar with software development or programming in general, take a look at _Beginning Perl_ by Curtis "Ovid" Poe. If not, look at _Learning Perl_ in the O'Reilly Perl book series (_The Llama book_), and make sure you get a edition. Perl has come a long way, and the code you've shown here tells me you are using at least a somewhat out of date resource to learn.

Comment: @simbabque, thanks for the suggestion, I will look into that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In perl, like in a lot of script languages, single ticks and double quotes have a different meaning even though they are both strings.

The single ticks are meant to preserve the literal nature of the string constant, so dollar variables and control sequences like \n are not evaluated.

Try using `"$filename"` with double quotes.

Also, in this case, since your string contains only the variable and nothing else, you can drop the quotes altogether and just pass `$filename`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If I use the double quotes, the script dies trying to open the file.

Comment: The output is "No such file or directory at ./test_perl.pl line 7."

Comment: This is called _interpolation_. And as you correctly say it makes no sense to use it here. That last bit should go to the top of the answer. ;)

Comment: @simbabque I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean, could you please elaborate? I am completely new at Perl, so I apologise for the stupid questions.

Comment: @GrimReaper, my comment was directed at Ryan regarding their answer. It was not about your code. Just a suggestion on how to improve the answer so I would upvote it. As it stands it's not correct enough for my taste to vote on it.

Comment: Perl's `open` won't create directories. Does the directory `/home/python` exist? If not, you'll want to look into functions like `mkdir` or the `File::Path` module. Also, be aware you won't be able to create directories like that unless you run as root, which is a bad idea.

Comment: @RyanCalhoun That was the problem! Thank you so much! I feel like an idiot now, thanks for explaining what I did wrong!